# Is there a simple way to print Sprint Burnd-down charts from TFS 2012?

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2012 for our project  and the Scrum process template.

I have the problem that the development environment is separated from the "ordinary" network, making it impossible for stakeholders to access the project page easily. Therefore we have an ordinary board where we put the most important information, and keeps updating it to show progress.

Now I wonder if there is a simple way to be able to print the different TFS charts, and especially the Sprint burndown chart?

Right now I just make screendumps, but maybe there is some other way that I don't know about?!

Regards, 
Humble

Answer (score 0):

As TFS is a production system that is responsible for managing an organizational asset it should be in the Production domain.

The second best solution would be to create a one way active directory trust between Prod and Dev so that Prod accounts can log into Dev.

The third best solution would be to have reporting services email the reports out on a scheduled bases. You can do burn down and other reports.

Ultimately your stakeholders should have full access to TFS to at least view and comment on the backlog and create work items. That you have a separate domain for dev shows a distinct lack of trust within your organization and a systemic use of Silos. Can your testers access TFS? What about your deployment teams? How do you manage rationalization of Portfolio->Dev->Comercialisation->Deploy->Monitor cycle?